# Remove notification of new privileges for mods

Tags: feature-request, android-app, moderator-abilities

I'm a mod on freelancing.se, and I get notifications in my feed that I'm close to unlocking a new privilege on my site. I'd like to recommend it doesn't show that in the feed, since clicking it does nothing, and mods already have all the privileges